# Using tikzpicture along with tcblisting

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, tcolorbox, tcblisting

I am trying to use `tikzpicture` along with `tcblisting`. Basically, I am trying to design a figure to show the use of Java compiler, which converts Java source code into bytecode.

See below the code snippet-

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{
        title=Source Code,
        hbox,
        listing only,
        listing options={
            language=Java,
            basicstyle=\ttfamily,
            keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
            stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
            commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
            morecomment={[l][\color{magenta}]{\#}},
        }
    }
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[single arrow, draw, fill=red!40, text centered, text width=2cm, minimum width=2cm, font=\large] {Java Compiler};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tcblisting}{
        title=Bytecode,
        hbox,
        listing only,
        listing options={
            language=C++,
            basicstyle=\ttfamily,
            keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
            stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
            commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
            morecomment={[l][\color{magenta}]{\#}},
        }
    }
    HelloWord.class
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

Please see the generated figure below-
[image]

**I want to keep both of the `tcblisting` vertically top aligned and `tikzpicture` vertically center align.**

Comment: Do you intend to keep the standalone class or is this going to be part of a document with another class?

Comment: @marmot: anything is fine. I generally design figures in standalone class and later add them in the main file.

Answer (score 8):

`tcolorboxes` are more or less `tikzpictures`, therefore, they can be `remembered as` and be referenced as other `TikZ nodes`.

Following solution uses Torbjørn T. code and adds `enhanced, remember as = ...` options to each `tcolorbox`. They are drawn with a certain distance between them and later on the `arrow` is drawn adjusted to this distance using `calc` library.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox} %<---- Added [most]  option
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows, calc} %<--- Added `calc` library

\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{
        title=Source Code,
        enhanced, % <-- added
        remember as = source, % <-- added
        box align=top, 
        hbox,
        listing only,
        listing options={
            language=Java,
            basicstyle=\ttfamily,
            keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
            stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
            commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
            morecomment={[l][\color{magenta}]{\#}},
        }
    }
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
\end{tcblisting}
\hspace{3cm}    %<---- Fix the space between boxes
\begin{tcblisting}{
        title=Bytecode,
        enhanced, % <-- added
        remember as=bytecode, % <-- added
        box align=top, 
        hbox,
        listing only,
        listing options={
            language=C++,
            basicstyle=\ttfamily,
            keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
            stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
            commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
            morecomment={[l][\color{magenta}]{\#}},
        }
    }
    HelloWord.class
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
% added `let` construction to compute minimum height
% added `anchor` and positioning coordinate
    \path let \p1=($(bytecode.north west)-(source.north east)$) in
        node[single arrow, draw, fill=red!40, text centered, 
             text width=18mm, minimum height={veclen(\x1,\y1)}, 
             font=\large, anchor=after tail] (arr) at 
                  ([yshift=-5mm]source.north east) {Java Compiler};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Add `box align=top` to align the two `tcolorbox`es at the top, then set the `baseline` key of the `tikzpicture` to something useful, see code.
With `baseline=(arr.before tip)` you get the output in the screenshot. `arr` is the name I gave to the arrow node. If you want to position it differently, you can use a length (e.g. `baseline=2cm`), or even something like `baseline={([yshift=5mm]arr.before tip)}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{
        title=Source Code,
        box align=top, % <-- added
        hbox,
        listing only,
        listing options={
            language=Java,
            basicstyle=\ttfamily,
            keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
            stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
            commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
            morecomment={[l][\color{magenta}]{\#}},
        }
    }
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Prints "Hello, World" to the terminal window.
        System.out.println("Hello, World");
    }
}
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  baseline=(arr.before tip)
% or you can use a specific length, adjust to your liking
%  baseline=1cm
]

% added (arr) to name the node
    \node[single arrow, draw, fill=red!40, text centered, text width=2cm, minimum width=2cm, font=\large] (arr) {Java Compiler};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tcblisting}{
        title=Bytecode,
        box align=top, % <-- added
        hbox,
        listing only,
        listing options={
            language=C++,
            basicstyle=\ttfamily,
            keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
            stringstyle=\color{red}\ttfamily,
            commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
            morecomment={[l][\color{magenta}]{\#}},
        }
    }
    HelloWord.class
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```